# How can I access data from loaded from an IndexedDB objectStore?

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

Here is my code I want to return getConn.result and use it in my js page. Could you help me?

```js
function readObjectStore(storeName) {
  // Open (or create) the database
  var open = indexedDB.open("Publisher", 1);
  open.onupgradeneeded = function () {}
  open.onsuccess = function () {
    var db = open.result;
    var tx = db.transaction(storeName, "readwrite");
    var store = tx.objectStore(storeName);
    if (storeName == "connectionStrings") {
      var getConn = store.getAll();
      getConn.onsuccess = function () {
        return getConn.result;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: this is an asynchronous code so you need to use a callback that you pass to `readObjectStore` or make it return a promise.

Comment: Thanks marzelin I use it and get answer.